I can't open the file in pycharm
I installed the latest version of Pycharm 2024.1 and now I can't open the files. Previously I had Pycharm 2022.1. I have reset my computer and reinstalled pycharm several times, what could be the problem?

Edit
It works on version 2023.3.5

The problem was the "aiXcoder Code Completer" plugin, it does not work on version 2024.1
